# How to call requestFocus for a TextField created at runtime?

Tags: flutter, widget, focus

I'm trying to call requestFocus method on a TextField that was created at runtime, however the function callFocus() is only working if I set the delay of 2 seconds, probably because the TextField is being created asynchronously. The question is, how to call requestFocus after TextField is ready?

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  title: appBarTitle,
  centerTitle: true,
  actions: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: actionIcon,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
              this.actionIcon = Icon(Icons.navigate_next);
              this.appBarTitle = TextField(
                controller: editingController,
                focusNode: _searchInsideFocus,
                onChanged: (findNext) {
                  webView.findAllAsync(find: findNext);
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                    hintText: "Search...",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ).;
            } else {
              webView.findNext(forward: true);
            }
          });
          callFocus();
        },
      ),
    ),
  )
```

```dart
Future<Null> callFocus() async {
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 2)); //only works if delayed
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_searchInsideFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is no callback, from a parent widget, that allows you to know when the text field has been rendered, if it is dynamically added to the tree in this manner. Instead, just move the request for focus into a new wrapper widget that does know when it has rendered for the first time, and therefore can request focus after render has happened, like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextWrapper({
    this.controller,
    this.focusNode,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

  @override
  _TextWrapperState createState() => _TextWrapperState();
}

class _TextWrapperState extends State<TextWrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      focusNode: widget.focusNode,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
        hintText: 'Search...',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onRendered(Duration _) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(widget.focusNode);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onRendered);
  }
}
```

Then inside your `Scaffold()` do this instead:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: appBarTitle,
  centerTitle: true,
  actions: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: actionIcon,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
              this.actionIcon = Icon(Icons.navigate_next);
              this.appBarTitle = TextWrapper(
                controller: editingController,
                focusNode: _searchInsideFocus,
                onChanged: (findNext) {
                  webView.findAllAsync(find: findNext);
                },
              );
            } else {
              webView.findNext(forward: true);
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks! I didn't know about the wrapper widget concept.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the focus is not transferred immediately because after state mutation flutter engine tries to restore focus on the active before changing state widget (i.e. `IconButton`). If in the new state widget with focus is gone, the next widget with the `autofocus` property `true` will be active.

This behavior is worth using. Just set the `autofocus` property of text field to `true` and remove button after clicking:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabPageState createState() => _LabPageState();
}

class _LabPageState extends State<LabPage> {
  bool inSearch = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: inSearch
              ? TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  onChanged: (findNext) {
                    // webView.findAllAsync(find: findNext);
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                )
              : Text('My App Title'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            inSearch
                ? Container()
                : Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          inSearch = true;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
          ]),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```